# в моей программе выполняется код, даже если условия его выполнения не обеспечены

Tags: python

что бы я не вводил в user_choise,всегда выполняется лишь первая условная конструкция

````
```import random
#место для кода самой программы
game_number = random.randint(1,10) #создаю случайное число
user_choise = input("Привет,это игра угадай число,сыграем?Есть 2 режима:первый без подсказок,второй с ними(1 - первый, 2 - второй):") #создаю поле ввода
if "1" or "Первый" or "первое" or "первый режим" == user_choise: #проверяю режим
    print("Итак,выбери число от 1 до 10:")
    print(game_number)
    user_number = input("")
    if int(user_number) == game_number:
        print("Поздравляю,победа твоя!;)")
    else:
        print("Ну,возможно повезет в другой раз")
if "1" or "Первый" or "первое" or "первый режим" != user_choise:
    print("Я не понимаю такого")```
````

Comment: @andreymal,Спасибо огромное,ошибка действительно была в этом,еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно лучше сделать вот так:

```
if user_choise == '1' or user_choise =="Первый" or user_choise =="первое" or user_choise == "первый режим":
```

такой код всегда будет возвращать 1, соответственно переменная user_choise всегда будет сравниваться с единицей.

```
"1" or "Первый" or "первое" or "первый режим" # вернет 1
```

Comment: лучше делать через ``in``. Это и короче и проще читать.